# How can I make Appium and the app launch automatically before every test in Java for iOS with heels classes?

Tags: java, ios, intellij-idea, automated-tests, appium

Now that I am able to open Appium and then running a script launching the app on a simulator, How can I launch Appium and the app before every test?
How can this be made with helper classes that are called on the test scripts?

Answer (score 2):

Not much familiar with java but there is @beforeTest @beforeSuite annotations in Testng, which might be worth to look on.
Here is a helping link

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-beforesuite-example/

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to have it as a class in java and not with testNG.

Answer (score 0):

Write one base class and write your code to launch the app inside the constructor of base class.

And then extend the base class to all your test classes. The base class constructor will be called automatically before the child class is executed.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your appium server with --override-session flag.

```
node main.js --override-session
```

And then for each session you have to creare a new driver...

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://192.168.1.50:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
//1. start doing things here...
//1. end
//Launch app again
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://192.168.1.50:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
//2. start doing things here...
//2. end
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've searched separately for the 2 things I needed here. one is the launching of the Appium with Java code and found this:

@Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

```
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"))
            .withAppiumJS(
                    new File("/usr/local/bin/appium"))
            .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723));

    service.start();
```

Works great. 
The second thing I wanted to do is automatically launch Appium and even the app. and this can be done as I've searched tried and saw by @BeforeClass annotation on a separate class, creating static methods with the launch functions and then extending that separate class on the test class.